# Does anyone knows a diagram represents all Java packages

Tags: java, package

after a few semesters learning Java, I just realized that, I've been importing classes from various packages (such as java.lang.Long, java.io.File ,  javax.swing.JDialog ... ) without really understanding about Java package system.

The way it happened was, I need to do something, then search for solutions on internet, and then, people say that I'd use these things, including those classes from these packages. Therefore I know that this class is included in that package. But I didn't know the remaining classes of that package, and the remaining package of Java. Therefore, if I have a new problem, I'll have to ask for solutions again.

So, what I want, is an overview of Java package system, all the packages in Java, and all the classes in each package (most frequently used ones of course as nobody knows everything). I've found many documents. But it's pretty hard to understand to me, especially try to remember something I've never used before.

But, I've found many diagram, of class construction in a single package and the realationship between them (like in http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jfc/ , http://doc.sumy.ua/prog/java/exp/figs/exj2_0901.gif). I can say, it's really a lot easier to understand with these diagrams. But as I say, I want an overview of all packages in Java.

So, I want a diagram with all packages putting together with their relationships. I tried to search but couldn't find it, but still i hope maybe someone tried spending their valuable time to write such a thing.

I'm very grateful for your help, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try the javadoc for getting overview of java packages. It might not have the diagrams, but it has nice overviews and relationships of all the packages in java.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/